# how to interact with location pop up in iOS 17 Appium java

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium, ios17

I am trying to click on the 'Allow once' button in the location pop-up in iOS but for some reason, I am unable to interact with it.

I tried with both xpaths and accept alert still the result was same.
Xapth I used `//*[contains(@label, 'Allow Once')]`
and `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

[image]